# How to input variables in logger formatter?

Tags: python, logging

I currently have:

```
FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', filename=LOGFILE, level=getattr(logging, options.loglevel.upper()))
```

... which works great, however I'm trying to do:

```
FORMAT = '%(MYVAR)s %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
```

and that just throws keyerrors, even though `MYVAR` is defined.

Is there a workaround? `MYVAR` is a constant, so it would be a shame of having to pass it everytime I invoke the logger.

Thank you!

Comment: If `MYVAR` is going to have always the same value, isn't `FORMAT = '{} %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'.format(MYVAR)` a possible alternative?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use a [custom filter](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information):

```
import logging

MYVAR = 'Jabberwocky'


class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    """
    This is a filter which injects contextual information into the log.
    """
    def filter(self, record):
        record.MYVAR = MYVAR
        return True

FORMAT = '%(MYVAR)s %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addFilter(ContextFilter())

logger.warning("'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves")
```

yields

```
Jabberwocky 24/04/2013 20:57:31 - WARNING - 'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much - that's indeed the correct way to proceed!

Comment: Doesn't work form me in python 2.7. The solution is adding the `ContextFilter()` to a handler instead.

Answer (score 12):

You could use a custom `Filter`, as `unutbu` says, or you could use a `LoggerAdapter`:

```
import logging

logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logging.getLogger(__name__), {'MYVAR': 'Jabberwocky'})

FORMAT = '%(MYVAR)s %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

logger.warning("'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves")
```

which gives

Jabberwocky 25/04/2013 07:39:52 - WARNING - 'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves

Alternatively, just pass the information with every call:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

FORMAT = '%(MYVAR)s %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

logger.warning("'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves", extra={'MYVAR': 'Jabberwocky'})
```

which gives the same result.

Since MYVAR is practically constant, the `LoggerAdapter` approach requires less code than the `Filter` approach in your case.

Comment: Does ``logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)`` change the format for all the loggers? How to change it only for this new logger adapter? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Borrowing from a comment above, I found that the simplest way to do this when the variable is static for all log entries is to simply include it in the formatter itself:

`FORMAT = '{} %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'.format(MYVAR)`

With this method, no custom class implementation is required, and you don't have to worry about methods which are not defined for the various classes (`LoggerAdapter` and `CustomAdapter`), such as `addHandler()`. Admittedly, this is probably less Pythonic but it worked as a quick solution for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
locals()
FORMAT = '%(MYVAR)s %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
```

locals() should return a dictionary of all variables locally available, then the error.
If you don't see it in there, then its not locally available. This will prove its not defined properly. We would need more code to see if it was defined improperly. Alternatively you can try "globals()" to check the global ones.... but you probably arent putting "global MYVAR " in the definition that outputs FORMAT

Comment: I tried printing locals and I can see my var as part of the output: 'MYVAR': 'blahblah'