# How to add custom data in Python logs

Tags: python

I am using python logging.

Once I get a handle to logger object, I do the following to log

```
logger.info("this is my log message")
```

My requirement is this:

1. In the above custom log info message, I would want to pass more parameters like the following:

   ```
   custom_name = "DISPLAY"
   logger.info("this is my log message", custom_name)
   ```
2. custom_name parameter should be consumed by the log formatter's `custom_name` placeholder as shown below

   ```
   formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(custom_name)s:%(name)s %(message)s')
   ```

I read articles, stackoverflow posts, python logging documentation. I could only find how to create custom placeholders in the formatter.
I am not sure how to pass those custom placeholder values from the log statement itself. Can someone point me to a resource or let me know how to accomplish this ?

#### Edit:

I could do something like this

```
import logging

CUSTOM_VAR= 'myCustomVarValue'


class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):

    def filter(self, record):
        record.CUSTOM_VAR= CUSTOM_VAR
        return True

FORMAT = '%(CUSTOM_VAR)s %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addFilter(ContextFilter())

logger.info("'this is info message")
```

The above works fine. However, `CUSTOM_VAR` is a static value. How can I dynamically pass this value from `log.info` ??

Comment: Seems already answered here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203908/how-to-input-variables-in-logger-formatter

Comment: not really as that one talks about a static parameter. I found a way to do it which I have posted in the answer below

Answer (score 2):

In config.py we can set CUSTOM_VAR using **contextvars** class and we can update dynamically inside the main code.

```
import contextvars
CUSTOM_VAR = contextvars.ContextVar("CUSTOM_VAR", default=None)
```

Inside main code we can update CUSTOM_VAR like this

```
CUSTOM_VAR.set("DISPLAY")
```

we can use set CUSTOM_VAR inside logger file

```
import logging
from config import CUSTOM_VAR


class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):

    def filter(self, record):
        if not hasattr(record, 'CUSTOM_VAR'):
            record.custom_name= CUSTOM_VAR.get()
            return True

FORMAT = '%(custom_name)s %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addFilter(ContextFilter())

logger.info("'this is info message",extra=CUSTOM_VAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish it the following way:

In log config code, have your formatter declared like this:

```
 formatter = logging.Formatter(
   '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s,%(traceId)s %(packageName)s %(message)s')
```

Now in the code, where you have the log statements, have such statements written like this where you pass extra param values dynamically:

```
logger.info("custom log message goes here.....",
            extra={'traceId': 'XDDF4543GG', 'packageName': 'myPackage'})
```

corresponding log entry would look like this:

```
2017-05-15 17:59:24,101 INFO [my-proj-name,XDDF4543GG] myPackage custom log message goes here.....
```

Also, if you don't put all extra params in log.info then you would get a keyError error message.